# Stopping the manipulation of variables used for data collection?

Tags: java

I am working on a project in java and I was hoping to be able to collect statistics from the client and a possible problem that I fear will occur is the manipulation of the variables used for collection which will lead to illegitimate statistics. Is it in any way possible to prevent the manipulation of variables or is it always possible?

For example, I want to log the actions made per hour from the client. The variable acting as a counter for the amount of actions performed is manipulated and a much larger amount is added to the counter. This data is then uploaded to the server (Of course using a multi-tier architecture to prevent even more possible problems) and considered 'legit'.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the data is uploaded, there are various ways to secure the information.

If you are uploading some kind of text or data file, using basic encryption, even a ZIP with a password, should be sufficient to stop casual users from changing the information.

Your application could also simply use RMI or a web service to upload the information, never giving the user the change to manipulate the data.

All of this of course assumes that the application itself gathers the information - if users have the opportunity to enter the data, there's no real way of preventing them from giving you bogus information.

Without knowing if this is a desktop or web application, I'm going to suggest you encrypt your upload files somehow. It doesn't have to be complicated, just enough so someone can't edit it in a text editor.

Just remember that if something runs on the client machine, it can be manipulated. Java is not a secure language, nothing is, for that matter, and while you can do many things to secure applications, there's always someone just a little smarter out there that can crack it.

Comment: You gave me a few ideas Ewald, thanks a lot! I would Up Vote you but I don't have the reputation required, my apologies. It is a desktop application by the way. Once again, thanks!

Comment: No worries - as long as it helped you.  Desktop applications are great, you can secure them quite a bit more than web applications. It won't be fool proof, but it will prevent casual users from manipulating the data. Add a comment if you get stuck, there's lots of really smart folks on Stack Overflow that can help you, I learn something new every day.

Answer (score 0):

If I was doing this, I'd do the accumulation of the statistics on a secured machine.  Have the primary data gathering code send "event" message to the accumulator, and have the accumulator keep a log of the raw events and their arrival timestamps.  This won't prevent people manipulating the stats, but it could make it easier to detect suspicious patterns after the fact.

Building on that idea, you could arrange that event generator application (on the user's computer) uses some kind of handshaking involving a shared secret or public/private key encryption.  I don't think you can fully secure this, but security-by-obscurity could be enough to deal with attempts to cheat by people without the skills to reverse engineer the code.

But like Ewald says, any algorithmic process can be reverse engineered by someone who has sufficient control of the hardware it runs on.  If the process needs to use a "secret" to operate, then that secret can be revealed.